# MUI Chip: How to disable the overflow/ellipsis?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

When using MUI in React, I want to have flexible width for the Chip component depending on the label inside. For example, if it is a long label, the Chip should have a wider width. If the label is short, the Chip can have a small width too. In conclusion the whole label should be visible inside the Chip and there should be no ellipsis.

Answer (score 1):

This is what I have done:

```
<Chip
  sx={{
    padding: '0 8px',
    '& .MuiChip-label': {
      overflow: 'visible',
    },
  }}
  ...
/>
```